# Is it possible to replace Batchnorm with FusedBatchNorm on a frozen inference graph?

Tags: tensorflow, inference

I am trying to replace a BatchNorm layer with a FusedBatchNorm layer in a pretrained model (a .pb file) in tensorflow. Is this actually possible without changing the dataflow of the model and if so, is there a working example of someone doing so?